# SVG blurry before and after CSS animation on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg, css-animations, gecko

I want to animate parts of an SVG logo with CSS transforms. The unanimated SVG is rendered perfectly fine, also during the animation, everythings looks crystal clear.

However, in fill-state, that is, during animation delay and after finishing the animation, firefox totally blurs the animated part of the graphic.

The issue arrises only in Mozilla Firefox, both on my Mac and Windows system. In chrome and safari it looks as intended.

```css
  #gull {
    fill: #59E9CF;
    -webkit-animation: gull-flight 5s linear 3s 1 normal both;
    -moz-animation: gull-flight 5s linear 3s 1 normal both;
    animation: gull-flight 5s linear 5s 1 normal both;
  }
  @keyframes gull-flight {
    0% {
      transform: matrix(0.976, -0.216, 0.216, 0.976, -9.5, 71.6);
      fill: #404041;
    }
    100% {
      transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes gull-flight {
    0% {
      transform: matrix(0.976, -0.216, 0.216, 0.976, -9.5, 71.6);
      fill: #404041;
    }
    100% {
      transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    }
  }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 808 138" version="1.1">
  <path d="M11.0944925 129.4 L11.0944925 23.2 C11.0944925 20.3 9.6 18.8 6.5 18.7 L-0.00275138279 18.3 L-0.00275138279 3 L32.5369357 3 L32.5369357 46.8 C38.0855577 41.7 45.5 39.1 54.9 39.1 C66.4981706 39.1 75.7 43 82.5 50.8 C89.2337637 58.7 92.6 69.7 92.6 83.9 C92.6271358 119.5 77.7 137.3 47.9 137.3 C41.4789298 137.3 34.7 136.6 27.6 135 C20.5592493 133.5 15 131.6 11.1 129.4 M32.5369357 69.4 L32.5369357 117.4 C37.2234577 119.8 42.6 121.1 48.8 121.1 C62.8663453 121.1 69.9 109.6 69.9 86.8 C69.8915427 66 63 55.5 49.2 55.5 C44.743904 55.5 40.9 56.8 37.5 59.4 C34.2061079 62 32.5 65.3 32.5 69.4"
  />
  <path d="M150.264937 17 C157.180079 18.5 161.5 22.4 163.2 28.6 C164.333674 32.6 164.6 37.6 164 43.5 L176.008708 55.3 L191.517336 49.9 C193.470818 44.1 196 39.6 199.3 36.2 C203.705962 31.6 209.4 30.1 216.3 31.7 C220.80122 32.7 224.2 34.7 226.5 37.6 L245.88466 30.8 C243.912835 28.4 241.4 25.9 238.4 23.6 C233.87946 20.1 228 17.6 220.8 16 C210.465192 13.7 200.3 14.8 190.3 19.4 C188.123964 20.5 186 21.9 184 23.5 C183.510812 22.1 182.9 20.8 182.2 19.6 C180.099097 15.9 176.8 12.4 172.3 8.9 C167.855444 5.4 162 2.9 154.8 1.3 C144.441176 -1 134.3 0.1 124.3 4.7 L137.938742 18.1 C141.478854 16.3 145.6 15.9 150.3 17"
  id="gull" />
</svg>
```

I have minimized the svg code to demonstrate: the letter 'b' remains sharp, while the 'gull' is first blurred, then sharp when moving and blurs again after the animation. (hint: play in full-screen mode to see what I mean)

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I just tried with Firefox 35 and for me, it looks perfect.... maybe solved in last versions?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is just a limitation of the current build. Like webGL, or other edge stuff - the browser just doesn't do it well yet - it's not really something you can fix, but something that you work up against. Until it is rounded out in future builds (note that there is no guarantee it will ever be...) - you could try that transformZ hack, or you could test for it with modernizr, and omit it in the case where it doesn't look cool.